# charset tables for sphinx in utf8

Tags: character-encoding, sphinx

I am searching for charset_tables for some languages for Sphinx. I don't know how to build them and I will be very thankful if anyopne can help me.

I need the charset_tables for: Dansk, Finnish, Norwegian, Hungarian, Slovakian, Polnish, Spanish, French.

I have found this post (http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=19#2857 ) and a character values for common european languages, but for which?

Thank you very much!

Best Regards
Nik

Answer (score 0):

Use [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters), to write charset table you needed.
This is a list of unicode characters in suitable format.

But you need to spend some time to make your own chartable.